# Combine multiple git diff output files into one unified file

Tags: git, git-diff

I need to combine multiple git diff output files that are non-sequential into one big unified diff file.

`git diff rev1 rev5 > diff1.txt`

`git diff rev44 rev551 > diff2.txt`

This produces a `diff1.txt` and `diff2.txt` each having modifcations, deletions and updates on lines, in a standard git diff format, in a unified way.

I would in the end like to:

`combine diff1.txt and diff2.txt` into one unified diff file that combines the 2 diff files , much like a 'git squash' does or 'merge', but with just the output of these 2 diff files.

I cannot do anything similar or go around this because i generated these 2 diff files from SVN via the `svn diff --git` diff tool that produces the difference between the current and previous revision in a git diff format compatible. So i need to `squash` these 2 diff files into one.

Comment: By squash do you mean concatenate?

Comment: I don't want to append, but merge the diffs, so that if line 2 was modified, then deleted, i want to see the final output as deleted.

Comment: Could you diff between rev1 and rev551?

Comment: Just to clarify. You want to produce a unified diff as described here? https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Detailed-Unified.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the request does not make sense.

Ultimately, a diff is a set of instructions: *apply these changes*—where a *change* is from some set of modification operations, usually "delete line(s)", "insert line(s)", and/or "change line(s)"—*to these specified lines*.  Following the instructions will transform one file, the left side of the diff, into a second file, the right side.  In the case of `git diff` unified diff output, the instruction-set includes some context for both left and right side files and the instructions are limited to "delete lines" and "insert lines" (or delete words and insert words).

One of the key properties here is that *there are only two files involved* in this operation.  If the diff provides some context (as Git's do), the context helps to ensure that whoever *receives* the diff actually has the same input file as whoever made the diff.  Applying the diff should therefore result in the same output file.

In your case, though, you have *four* files.  Your first diff says *apply these changes to file `rev1` to produce file `rev5`*.  Your second diff says *apply these changes to file `rev44` to produce file `rev555`*.  There is no guarantee that `rev44` resembles `rev5` in any way.  It *might* resemble `rev5` somehow, but it might not.  Without *many* additional constraints on the input files, it is simply impossible to combine the instructions like this.  A single diff, no matter how it is constructed, will only change *one* input file to *one* output file.  You have two inputs and two outputs, so you need two diffs.  If you wish to combine them, *you* must construct the (single) input and output files.  You are the only one with all four files so you are the only one in a position to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As @torek points out, this is prone to conflicts.  Your best bet is one of

```
git rebase --onto rev5 rev44 rev551^0
git diff rev1
```

or if rev44..rev551 has a lot of commits,

```
git checkout rev5
git diff rev44..rev551 | git apply -3
git diff rev1
```

either of which has Git to do all the automatic merging possible and at least finding all the hard parts for you to resolve manually.

The `^0` is just "I want that commit, not whatever name points to it", in case you're using a branch name to point to rev551 the rebase won't move the branch tip, we're making throwaway content just to see the results, so there's no need for names.

If you don't want to touch your current work tree, make a throwaway scratch clone and do the work there,

```
git branch -f scratch rev5
git clone -sb scratch . `mktemp -d`
cd $_
```

and then whichever of the above works best for you.

---

ah: just noticed you don't even have a git history, this is git-formatted diffs from svn.

I feel pretty confident saying you need Git's merge machinery to resolve the conflicts that can come from this.  It's been a *long* time since I did svn, something like this sequence should do it:

```
svn checkout rev1
git init
git add .; git commit -m rev1
svn checkout rev5
git add .; git commit -m rev5
svn checkout rev44
git add .; git commit -m rev44
svn checkout rev551
git add .; git commit -m rev551
```

then the above rebase should get what you want, you can use `:/rev44` to refer to the latest commit that's got a "rev44" in its message, it's a regex so `:/rev5$` finds the latest whose message ends `rev5`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over thinking this. Will this work?
Create the first diff

```
git diff rev1 rev5 > diff.txt
```

Append the second diff to the first. Note the `>>`

```
git diff rev44 rev551 >> diff.txt
```

Comment: I don't want to append, but merge the diffs, so that if line 2 was modified, then deleted, i want to see the final output as deleted.